# Typo3 Database update from typo3 v7.6 to typo3 v11.53

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I want to update typo3 `v7.6` to `v11.5.3`. I copied the files from the latest version to the old installation. The files are updates but I am facing database issues. The DB structure of `v11.5.3` is different from `v7.6`. I need to migrate my data from `v7.6` database to `v11.53` database. Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

The core does only ship migrations for 2 major versions. Therefore you need to switch 1st to version 9 and do all the upgrade steps there and after that you can update to 11 and do the update wizards of 10+11.

All upgrade wizards can either be run via cli or via Install Tool.

Additional code migrations can easily done by using tools like [rector](https://github.com/sabbelasichon/typo3-rector)

---

I personally don't care if the the frontend works in the intermediate versions and fix that at the end but as 7.6. is really old (and the used code could even be outdated in those old times) it will take a bit of manual work.

Comment: Nicole has written a package for upgrading from v7 to v10 (https://packagist.org/packages/ichhabrecht/core-upgrader). This way, you can execute the wizards for v7->v8->v9->v10 in a single step (via CLI) and do not need each core-version in between.